# How do i display content when using Chakra-ui SideBar in a React Application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I exported the SideBar and Imported it in my App.jsx

SideBar.jsx

```
'use client'

import {
    IconButton,
    Avatar,
    Box,
    CloseButton,
    Flex,
    HStack,
    VStack,
    Icon,
    useColorModeValue,
    Text,
    Drawer,
    DrawerContent,
    useDisclosure,
    Menu,
    MenuButton,
    MenuDivider,
    MenuItem,
    MenuList,
    Image
} from '@chakra-ui/react'
import {
    FiHome,
    FiTrendingUp,
    FiCompass,
    FiStar,
    FiSettings,
    FiMenu,
    FiBell,
    FiChevronDown,
} from 'react-icons/fi'

const LinkItems = [
    { name: 'Home', icon: FiHome },
    { name: 'Trending', icon: FiTrendingUp },
    { name: 'Explore', icon: FiCompass },
    { name: 'Favourites', icon: FiStar },
    { name: 'Settings', icon: FiSettings },
]

const SidebarContent = ({ onClose, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <Box
            transition="3s ease"
            bg={useColorModeValue('white', 'gray.900')}
            borderRight="1px"
            borderRightColor={useColorModeValue('gray.200', 'gray.700')}
            w={{ base: 'full', md: 60 }}
            pos="fixed"
            h="full"
            {...rest}>
            <Flex h="20" flexDirection="column" alignItems="center" mx="8" mb={75} mt={2} justifyContent="space-between">
                <Text fontSize="2xl" fontFamily="monospace" fontWeight="bold" mb={5}>
                    Dashboard
                </Text>
                <Image
                    borderRadius='full'
                    boxSize='75px'
                    src='https://marshallspetzone.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/1-1.jpg'
                    alt='Dog Profile'
                />
                <CloseButton display={{ base: 'flex', md: 'none' }} onClick={onClose} />
            </Flex>
            {LinkItems.map((link) => (
                <NavItem key={link.name} icon={link.icon}>
                    {link.name}
                </NavItem>
            ))}


        </Box>
    )
}

const NavItem = ({ icon, children, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <Box
            as="a"
            href="#"
            style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}
            _focus={{ boxShadow: 'none' }}>
            <Flex
                align="center"
                p="4"
                mx="4"
                borderRadius="lg"
                role="group"
                cursor="pointer"
                _hover={{
                    bg: 'cyan.400',
                    color: 'white',
                }}
                {...rest}>
                {icon && (
                    <Icon
                        mr="4"
                        fontSize="16"
                        _groupHover={{
                            color: 'white',
                        }}
                        as={icon}
                    />
                )}
                {children}
            </Flex>
        </Box>
    )
}

const MobileNav = ({ onOpen, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <Flex
            ml={{ base: 0, md: 60 }}
            px={{ base: 4, md: 4 }}
            height="20"
            alignItems="center"
            bg={useColorModeValue('white', 'gray.900')}
            borderBottomWidth="1px"
            borderBottomColor={useColorModeValue('gray.200', 'gray.700')}
            justifyContent={{ base: 'space-between', md: 'flex-end' }}
            {...rest}>
            <IconButton
                display={{ base: 'flex', md: 'none' }}
                onClick={onOpen}
                variant="outline"
                aria-label="open menu"
                icon={<FiMenu />}
            />

            <Text
                display={{ base: 'flex', md: 'none' }}
                fontSize="2xl"
                fontFamily="monospace"
                fontWeight="bold">
                Logo
            </Text>

            <HStack spacing={{ base: '0', md: '6' }}>
                <IconButton size="lg" variant="ghost" aria-label="open menu" icon={<FiBell />} />
                <Flex alignItems={'center'}>
                    <Menu>
                        <MenuButton py={2} transition="all 0.3s" _focus={{ boxShadow: 'none' }}>
                            <HStack>
                                <Avatar
                                    size={'sm'}
                                    src={
                                        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1619946794135-5bc917a27793?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=faces&fit=crop&h=200&w=200&s=b616b2c5b373a80ffc9636ba24f7a4a9'
                                    }
                                />
                                <VStack
                                    display={{ base: 'none', md: 'flex' }}
                                    alignItems="flex-start"
                                    spacing="1px"
                                    ml="2">
                                    <Text fontSize="sm">Justina Clark</Text>
                                    <Text fontSize="xs" color="gray.600">
                                        Admin
                                    </Text>
                                </VStack>
                                <Box display={{ base: 'none', md: 'flex' }}>
                                    <FiChevronDown />
                                </Box>
                            </HStack>
                        </MenuButton>
                        <MenuList
                            bg={useColorModeValue('white', 'gray.900')}
                            borderColor={useColorModeValue('gray.200', 'gray.700')}>
                            <MenuItem>Profile</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem>Settings</MenuItem>
                            <MenuItem>Billing</MenuItem>
                            <MenuDivider />
                            <MenuItem>Sign out</MenuItem>
                        </MenuList>
                    </Menu>
                </Flex>
            </HStack>
        </Flex>
    )
}

const SidebarWithHeader = () => {
    const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()

    return (
        <Box minH="100vh" bg={useColorModeValue('gray.100', 'gray.900')}>
            <SidebarContent onClose={() => onClose} display={{ base: 'none', md: 'block' }} />
            <Drawer
                isOpen={isOpen}
                placement="left"
                onClose={onClose}
                returnFocusOnClose={false}
                onOverlayClick={onClose}
                size="full">
                <DrawerContent>
                    <SidebarContent onClose={onClose} />
                </DrawerContent>
            </Drawer>
            {/* mobilenav */}
            <MobileNav onOpen={onOpen} />
            <Box ml={{ base: 0, md: 60 }} p="4">
                {/* Content */}
            </Box>
            )
        </Box>
    )
}

export default SidebarWithHeader
```

App.jsx

```
import { Spinner, Text } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import SidebarWithHeader from "./shared/SideBar.jsx";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {getCustomers} from "./services/client.js";

const App = () => {

    
    const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        getCustomers().then(res => {
            setCustomers(res.data);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        }).finally(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        })
    }, [])

    if(loading){
        return (
            <SidebarWithHeader>
                <Spinner
                    thickness='4px'
                    speed='0.65s'
                    emptyColor='gray.200'
                    color='blue.500'
                    size='xl'
                />
            </SidebarWithHeader>
        )
    }

    if(customers.length <= 0){
        return (
            <SidebarWithHeader>
                <Text>No customers available</Text>
            </SidebarWithHeader>
        )
    }
    console.log(customers)
    return (
        <SidebarWithHeader>
            {customers.map((customer, index) => (
                <p key={index}>{customer.name}</p>
            ))}
        </SidebarWithHeader>
    )
}

export default App;
```

For some reasons, customer data isn’t showing up, i get a blank page. Please how do i access the  element that is responsible for displaying content in the App.jsx file. what i've been doing is to make  a parent, and add children components within it but it's not working. Please help. Thanks.

[image: This is the blank page]

Comment: `SidebarWithHeader` does not taken any `children`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please how do i display content on the blank page?

Answer (score 0):

`SidebarWithHeader`, as a wrapper component, should consume and render a `children` prop, very likely where you've the `{/* Content */}` comment.

```js
const SidebarWithHeader = ({ children }) => {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
  const boxBg = useColorModeValue('gray.100', 'gray.900');

  return (
    <Box minH="100vh" bg={boxBg}>
      <SidebarContent
        onClose={onClose}
        display={{ base: 'none', md: 'block' }}
      />

      <Drawer
        isOpen={isOpen}
        placement="left"
        onClose={onClose}
        returnFocusOnClose={false}
        onOverlayClick={onClose}
        size="full"
      >
        <DrawerContent>
          <SidebarContent onClose={onClose} />
        </DrawerContent>
      </Drawer>

      {/* mobilenav */}
      <MobileNav onOpen={onOpen} />

      <Box ml={{ base: 0, md: 60 }} p="4">
        {children} {/* <-- children is the content */}
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to figure it out. Pretty new to JS. Appreciate the help.